# Passing this element object in javascript and reading element css attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a peculiar issue. I was using the `this` keyword to pass the element to a function in the HTML onclick event and for some reason the css attributes of the element is not showing, its showing blank: "" instead of 'purple'. This a specific use case and I never had this issue with other elements I pass to it, not sure why its doing that. Maybe the element doesn't have those attributes? I set it in the stylesheet, is it because the function is called before the stylesheet is set?

```js
function bb(e) {
  var a = e.style.background;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```css
.zz {
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid white;
    background:grey;
    color:black;
    margin-right:3vw;
    padding-left:2vw;
    padding-right:2vw;
}

.zz:hover {
    background:purple;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="bb(this)" class="zz">click me</div>
```

Results:

```
""
```

where I want it to be:

```
"purple"
```

Comment: You can't see styles from the CSS sheets in the element "style" attribute. You have to use `.getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: aha! thanks. is there a way to just get 1 attribute instead of all of them at once?

Comment: I don't *think* so, but it's been a really long time since I used it. I think that given the way the innards of the browser probably work, getting all of the properties is probably just as cheap (or expensive) as getting just one.

Comment: You can access the `backgroundColor` if that's what you mean?  `getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor`